# UNION types text and bigint cannot be matched

Tags: postgresql, union-all

I'm running a complex stored procedure and I'm getting an error when I have 3 unions, but with 2 unions no error. If I remove either of the top two unions it runs fine. If I make one of the NULLs a 0, it runs fine. The error is "UNION types text and bigint cannot be matched"

````
```lang-sql
SELECT NULL AS total_time_spent 
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY student_id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT NULL AS total_time_spent
FROM tbl2
GROUP BY student_id 
UNION ALL 
SELECT sum(cast(("value" ->> 'seconds') AS integer)) AS total_time_spent 
FROM tbl3 
GROUP BY student_id
```
````

I've tried all kinds of casting on the sum result or the sum input. The json that I'm pulling from is either NULL, [] or something like this:

```
[{"date": "2020-09-17", "seconds": 458}]
```

Comment: cast your `null` values to `bigint`:  `select null::bigint as total_time_spent. . . `  To see why you get that error, try this query:  `with input as (select null as total_time_spent) select pg_typeof(total_time_spent) from input;`  It returns `text`

Comment: And that won't result in the value being 0? Amazing!

Comment: No.  There is no interpolation or assumption of another value for actual `null` values.  The problem was that a `null` without context is assumed to be `null::text`.  The first `select` in the `union` therefore has that column defined as `null`, which causes the `union` to fail when your third `select` puts a `bigint` value in that column.

Comment: I did try casting it before but I thought it returned zero. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

According to the SQL standard, the NULL value exists in every data type, but lacking an explicit type cast, the first subquery resolves the data type to to `text` (earlier versions of PostgreSQL would have used `unknown` here, but we don't want this data type in query results).

The error message is then a consequence of the [type resolution rules for `UNION` in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/typeconv-union-case.html).

Use an explicit type case to avoid the problem:

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS bigint) FROM ...
UNION ...
```

Comment: Learning something new every day! This helped resolve my issue.